# Wordpress Cannot Create or Modify .htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, centos7

Wordpress cannot write a new .htacess file or modify one that I put in. I've set the owner to apache:apache and the file permissions are 644.

Update - I've read for hours on posts just like mine. It seems the criteria is this:

1. The user running the web service needs to own the .htaccess file (done).
2. The file permissions need to be set to 644 (done).

Output of `ls -Z .htaccess`:

```
-rwxr--r--. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/html/.htaccess
```

Comment: Is that the user your httpd is using? What distribution are you using?

Comment: centos 7, yes apache is running httpd.

Comment: If you're running CentOS the file most probably has the wrong selinux context. You can check this with `ls -Z .htaccess`

Comment: -rwxr--r--. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/html/.htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a system where SELinux is active (which is the default on CentOS) setting the normal permissions is not sufficient, you also have to make sure that the files have the correct SELinux context for the process that has to access the file.

Your .htaccess file has the SELinux context `httpd_sys_content_t`, which makes it only readable to the webserver. To make it writable to the webserver you need to change that context. I don't have a CentOS installation available right now to test it, but a quick internet search for `wordpress selinux` found that the context `public_content_rw_t` should be appropriate. You can change the context with this command:

```
chcon -t public_content_rw_t .htaccess
```

Note that you will also make the directories `plugins`,`themes` and `uploads` writable in a similar manner if you want WordPress to be able to upload files and install themes and plugins in a comfortable manner.

Comment: On a side note: critical files like the .htaccess should only made writable to the webserver when you are making thanges that require access to the file. If it is always writable you are opening the door for more exploits if a vulnerability is found in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Which user are you running your server instance as? Unless you are running SUExec for your executable scripts, you should be able to determine the correct user by running:

`ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v $(whoami) | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'`

Permissions 0744 is unnecessary. There will be no execution of .htaccess.

Either you change the ownership to root and make the permissions 0600 (only write-, readable by owner), this is the recommended solution.

If you want to make it world writable (NOT RECOMMENDED!) you can set the mode to 0666.

Comment: Do not - Under any production circumstances change the permissions to 0666. Doing so would potentially allow an unauthorized individual to make hanged to your .htaccess file.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 644. It was late when I gave up. I was just trying to make it through the post when I made that mistake.

Comment: I ran the command to see who was running httpd and it returned "apache".